# Why is the partial image link not working on my GitHub blog?

Tags: github

At first, I thought the issue was due to the script I added to make it work on responsive web, but even after removing the script, the partial image link still doesn't work.

Today marks my third day of studying, and I spent the whole day struggling with this issue while trying to decorate my blog

```
<img src="../images/map.png" usemap="#image-map">

<map name="image-map">
    <area target="_blank" alt="img" title="facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/" coords="4734,3163,6576,3722" shape="rect">
</map>
```

(https://github.com/stowball/jQuery-rwdImageMaps)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery-rwdImageMaps/1.6/jquery.rwdImageMaps.min.js"></script>
  <style>  
    img {
      max-width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <
  <img src="../images/2023-01-29-0001/map.png" usemap="#instaMap" width="500" height="500">
  <map name="instaMap">
    <area shape="rect" coords="4673,5113,5337,5737" href="https://www.instagram.com/">
    
  </map>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('img[usemap]').rwdImageMaps();
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you explain "doesn't work"? Does the image exist, is the relative path correct?

Comment: @Hanskesting The image address is correct, and the image is displayed on the blog, but nothing happens when I hover over the image with the mouse pointer. Even after trying both types of codes, the image link does not work at all